# how to check an array.. within an array? jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'd like to know how to check an array that got several variables in it.. something like that.
I can explain better with the code shown:

```
// Ignore the words in here, they are just there to explan.
var $array = [
  alpha = {
    name : $('.a'),
    date : $('.b'),
    street: $('.c')
  },
  beta = {
    name : $('.x'),
    date : $('.y'),
    street: $('.z')
  }      
];

/* So now I got this arrays.. withing an array? is that correct?
 * or what is this called?
 * and now I want to check each object's length, if its 0 -> return false and
 * throw out an error, if >= 1 go on and check the next. */

// Check if all needed elements for the toggle to work are existent 
$.each( $array, function(key, value) {
  if ( !value.length ) {
    alert("Could not find "+ '"' + value.selector +'"!')
    return false
  };
});
// Well obviously this doesnt work..
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should probably do research and know an **object** from an **array**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the names of properties of an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) with a [`for (... in ...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop:

```
/* since the array isn't a jQuery object, don't prefix the name with `$` */
var things = [
    /* array elements have integer, not string, indices. In any case, 
       "alpha = ..." is the wrong syntax to set properties. What it
       does is set a variable named "alpha".
     */
    {...},
    {...},
];

$.each(things, function(idx, item) {
  for (p in item) {
    if (! item[p].length) {
      /* alerts are disruptive; use other means of informing
         the user or developer.
       */
      //alert("Could not find "+ '"' + value.selector +'"!')
      return false;
    } /* blocks don't need semicolon separators */
  }
});
```

See also "[For .. in loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6773981/90527)"

Comment: what is the (p in item) here?

Comment: @MartinBroder: that's what the links are for.

Comment: Should probably also use hasOwnProperty in that loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty